# Next.js revalidate data not from fetch

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a dashboard server component that gets some data from a DB (no fetch) say this happens in getData(). I then have a button in a client component that does a POST (via fetch). When this POST happens, I want to trigger getData() to run again to get the new data. How can I accomplish this since I am not getting the data via fetch? Am I able to add a tag to getData() somehow so I can just call revalidateTag()?

I see [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries) in the docs, but that doesn't look like it supports on-demand revalidation.

Comment: can you post your getdata code

Comment: It just uses the mysql2 library to get data from a local DB

Comment: You could either convert that into an api route to then add a tag or you could potentially call router.refresh() as it refreshes the pages data

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to make getData() an api route because it is called from the server. Also, router.refresh() doesn't seem like a great solution because it will do much more than just re-calling the one getData() method. It seems like there should be a very easy way to solve this and I am just missing something

Comment: You can try with revalidatePath("/your-path")

Comment: I think that might work for this simple case, but what about my comment to Fabio's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [server component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components) in combination with the [revalidatePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath) function to bust the cache for your database queries on demand. Here is a "close-to-real-world" example:

```
// [app]/dashboard/page.tsx
export default async function DashboardPage(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const getData = async () => {
    "use server";
    const result = await db.query("users").findMany({});
    return result;
  };

  const setData = async (name: string) => {
    "use server";
    const result = await db.query("users").insert({ name });
    return result;
  };

  const initialData = await getData();

  return (
    <MyForm 
      getData={getData}
      setData={setData}
      initialData={initialData} 
     />
  );
}
```

Since you will be collecting the user input on the client side anyway. We pass both the `getData` and `setData` actions the the client component. The component will insert the data and then revalidate the path for the next user and update its own state for the needed UI feedback.

```
export default function MyForm(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { initialData, getData, setData } = props;

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(initialData);

  const insert = async () => {
    const result = await setData({ name });
    setUsers(prev => [...prev, result]);
    revalidatePath("/dashboard");
  };

  const refresh = async () => {
    const result = await getData();
    setUsers(result);
  };

  return (
    <section className="gap-2 flex flex-col">
      <ul>
        {users.map(user => <li key={user.id)>{user.name}</li>}
      </ul>

      <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-2">
        <button onClick={insertUser}>Save</button>
        <button onClick={refresh}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

As you can see, in this approach the client component has its own state that is updated immediately with the value of the database insertion. This provides feedback to the current user. After the state is updated, the path is revalidated so another user can see the changes too.

Comment: What if the DashboardPage component has more than one method that gets data? Say we need to get a list of users like your example but also a list of ... animals. How could we get both pieces of data on initial load but when we add to the list of users, get the new list of users (and don't get the list of animals again) and when we add to the list of animals, get the new list of animals (and don't get the list of users again)?a

Comment: @Makazau Well simple. **You don't re-fetch the users or animals** when using the above approach, you always update the local state and revalidate. So you probably only would need to add additional props for the "animals".

Comment: Thank you! I was misunderstanding but this makes sense. One more question. Say I have a few other server components in between DashboardPage and MyForm, and all of these components in the middle need the updated list of users and animals:

Dashboard (top level) - needs updated users/animals > Feed (second level) - needs updated users/animals > Card (third level) - needs updated users/animals > MyForm (fourth level) - adds to users/animals

How can I allow the Dashboard, Feed, and Card to have the updated data without doing another db query?

Comment: Approach is basically the same, make one database query and use something like [jotai](https://jotai.org/) with the `useHydrateAtoms` utility to provide a global state to all components instead of just one via prop drilling.

Comment: How can I get the state from jotai in my server component?

Comment: You can't access the jotai state on the server, but you can simply query the database if you need the most recent data, as mentioned in this approach the user always sees the most recent data and only on page load the data is queried anew. Although I think [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) can be accessed on the server.

Comment: I don't want to query the database again. I actually want to do an optimistic update triggered by the client. I know what the result of the POST will be, and I can just assume (optimistically update) that the POST will work and add the expected result to the "state". So doing another DB query is not what I want to do. Is the only way to do this to just use all client components? That makes me sad...

Comment: Check out [useOptimistic](https://react.dev/reference/react/useOptimistic).